# java Axis clint side Error unable to engage modules rampart

Tags: java, client-side, rampart

I'm trying to run my client-application
I run a java application there is no tomcat or jboss. I'am pure client-side.
I run it on eclipse.

the system start logging this messages

> INFO  (org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine:1098) - No
>   services directory was found under
>   C:\JavaDev\wsDemograficiPlugIn\ClientWsAnpr\axis-client\modules. INFO 
>   (org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine:1109) - No modules
>   directory was found under
>   C:\JavaDev\wsDemograficiPlugIn\ClientWsAnpr\axis-client\modules.

and when i try to engage module rampart exit with

> org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Unable to engage module : rampart

my code is

```
      Policy policy = loadPolicy("C:/JavaDev/wsDemograficiPlugIn/ClientWsAnpr/src_axis/sign-policy-client.xml");
  //TestConnStub stub = new TestConnStub();

  String modulesPath="C:/JavaDev/wsDemograficiPlugIn/ClientWsAnpr/axis-client/modules";
  //String axisXmlPath="C:/JavaDev/wsDemograficiPlugIn/ClientWsAnpr/axis-client/conf/axis2.xml";
  //ConfigurationContext configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(modulesPath,axisXmlPath);
  ConfigurationContext configContext = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem(modulesPath,null);
  TestConnStub stub = new TestConnStub(configContext);

  // configure and engage Rampart
  ServiceClient client = stub._getServiceClient();
  HashMap<String, AxisModule> modules = client.getAxisConfiguration().getModules();

  Set <String> keys = modules.keySet();
  Iterator itr = keys.iterator();
  while(itr.hasNext()) {
     Object element = itr.next();
     System.out.print(element + " ");
  }


  //client.engageModule("addressing"); 
  client.engageModule("rampart"); 

  Options options = client.getOptions();
  options.setProperty(RampartMessageData.KEY_RAMPART_POLICY,policy);
```

Answer (score 0):

The “repository” is a directory in the file system which has two sub directories called “services” and “modules”
for example

in my cfg modulesPath to be set to "C:/JavaDev/wsDemograficiPlugIn/ClientWsAnpr/axis-client/"